# Copy string value to another string?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var phoneUDID: String?
var temporaryUDID: String?
var customUDID: String?

let md5Data = MD5(string: UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString)

let md5Hex =  md5Data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()

self.phoneUDID = md5Hex

self.temporaryUDID = (md5Hex + "@gmail.com")

self.customUDID = self.temporaryUDID
```

Information: I am using Swift 3 by the way!

Question: Is the self.customUDID = self.temporaryUDID line correct to use? Since they are both strings, is this a safe way of copying a string's value to another string? I submitted my app to the app store and saw this booboo and thought that errors could arise. Please convince me i'm safe. Thanks

Comment: Are you worried about some copy-on-write issues?

Comment: @Carpsen90, I am just worried an error could arise! Is that line a safe piece of code, lol.

Comment: Nothing to worry about, unless you are doing more in the rest of your code. For more on copy-on-write have a look [here](https://marcosantadev.com/copy-write-swift-value-types/)

Comment: @Carpsen90, you are the real answer here, thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What possible error are you worried about? What "booboo" are you referring to? You ask *"Is the self.customUDID = self.temporaryUDID line correct to use?"* - use to do what? How else would you copy a string's value other than using `=`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`String` is a **value type** in Swift. So no, if you change one, the other won't change.

When you do

```
self.customUDID = self.temporaryUDID
```

A *new* string is created and stored in `customUDID`.

Example:

```
var s1 = "Foo"
var s2 = s1

s1 = "Bar"

print(s1,s2) //Prints "Bar Foo"
```